# JavaSound detecting microphone getting plugged in or removed

Tags: java, javasound

It seems like JavaSound doesn't detect when a USB Microphone is plugged in or removed.

If plugged in while my java application is running, its not detected. Worse, if unplugged it still thinks its a valid mixer.

I have to relaunch the VM. Is there any way around this? I'm running Java 1.6.0_24 on Windows 7.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390942/javasound-detect-device-change). The same problem appears to exist on OS X. Is this a limitation of JavaSound

Answer (score 1):

I have described my solution for the pure microphone detection here:
[Java Sound refresh Lines list after attaching a microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874713/java-sound-refresh-lines-list-after-attaching-a-microphone)
Unfortunately there is still a problem that the data lines stay in an inconsistent state.